# Remove several rows with zero values in a dataframe using python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

HI everybody i need some help with python.

I'm working with an excel with several rows, some of this rows has zero value in all the columns, so i need to delete that rows.

```
In 
 id a b c d 
 a  0 1 5 0 
 b  0 0 0 0
 c  0 0 0 0
 d  0 0 0 1 
 e  1 0 0 1

Out 
id a b c d 
a  0 1 5 0
d  0 0 0 1 
e  1 0 0 1
```

I think in something like show the rows that do not contain zeros, but do not work because is deleting all the rows with zero and without zero

```
path = '/Users/arronteb/Desktop/excel/ejemplo1.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')
df_zero = df[(df.OTC != 0) & (df.TM != 0) & (df.Lease != 0) & (df.Maint != 0) & (df.Support != 0) & (df.Other  != 0)]
```

Then i think like just show the columns with zero

```
In 
id a b c d 
a  0 1 5 0 
b  0 0 0 0
c  0 0 0 0
d  0 0 0 1 
e  1 0 0 1


Out 
id a b c d 
b  0 0 0 0
c  0 0 0 0
```

So i make a little change and i have something like this

```
path = '/Users/arronteb/Desktop/excel/ejemplo1.xlsx'
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx,'Sheet1')
df_zero = df[(df.OTC == 0) & (df.TM == 0) & (df.Lease == 0) & (df.Maint == 0) & (df.Support == 0) & (df.Other  == 0)]
```

In this way I just get the column with zeros. I need a way to remove this 2 rows from the original input, and receive the output without that rows. Thanks, and sorry for the bad English, I'm working on that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your input you can group by whether all the columns are zero or not, then access them, eg:

```
groups = df.groupby((df.drop('id', axis= 1) == 0).all(axis=1))
all_zero = groups.get_group(True)
non_all_zero = groups.get_group(False)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this dataframe:

```
df
Out: 
  id  a  b  c  d  e
0  a  2  0  2  0  1
1  b  1  0  1  1  1
2  c  1  0  0  0  1
3  d  2  0  2  0  2
4  e  0  0  0  0  2
5  f  0  0  0  0  0
6  g  0  2  1  0  2
7  h  0  0  0  0  0
8  i  1  2  2  0  2
9  j  2  2  1  2  1
```

Temporarily set the index:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

Drop rows containing all zeros and reset the index:

```
df = df[~(df==0).all(axis=1)].reset_index()

df
Out: 
  id  a  b  c  d  e
0  a  2  0  2  0  1
1  b  1  0  1  1  1
2  c  1  0  0  0  1
3  d  2  0  2  0  2
4  e  0  0  0  0  2
5  g  0  2  1  0  2
6  i  1  2  2  0  2
7  j  2  2  1  2  1
```

Comment: Maybe also in one step `df[(df.drop("id", 1) == 0).all(axis=1)]`? Not sure if any better though

Comment: Yes, that's definitely a cleaner way for this example. But I've gotten into the habit of setting the index because when you have multiple/complex conditions it starts to look cleaner (`df[(df>0) & (df<5) | (df==-1)]`)